# Different color on link if clicked

Tags: php, css, hyperlink

My website's main menu loads from a header.php file. When a user clicks a link in the menu, I want to highlight the clicked link in a different color.

```
    <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
```

This works perfectly when menu is written in all pages. But since the menu is large, I have moved it to a header.php and included that into all the pages so that I can modify the menu just once.

How can I change the color of the clicked link?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with [a:active](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp).

```
a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before include('header.php'), define a variable `$active_page = 'Homepage'` or `= 1` if you prefer to assign numbers to your pages. Then in your navigation:

```
    <li <?php if ($active_page == 'Homepage') echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a>Homepage</a></li>
```